# VBA Error Handling only works on first pass

Tags: excel, vba

My code is:

```
Sub zaa()
'code to find another open file that has the defined name "data" 
'    - useful where the name changes each month or week

For Each wb In Workbooks
  On Error GoTo abcd
  x = wb.Name
  Workbooks(x).Activate
  If Range("Data").Address <> "" Then y = wb.Name

  Exit Sub

abcd:
Next wb

End Sub
```

Basic goal to find an Excel file with a specific named range when I know it exists but don't know the file name as it changes each week or month. Aim is to find the file and exit the sub at that point (or then do other code on that file and exit rather than going to other files.)

I find it works okay if I only have two files open but not if have more (unless the target one is second in line). Whilst I can run with what I have I thought others may benefit from what I have and I can have a more robust solution.

UPDATE:
Thanks to all those who have responded & to Mitch for putting original post in readable format! (I have since learnt how to correct that issue and to be able to copy code directly - which I have indicated in some comments below that I was having trouble with.)
I have had varying degrees of success - code from PaulStock & Reafidy both worked for me originally but PaulStock code has stopped working for me. Responses & code from Jean-François Corbett and Chris Neilsen have been helpful to me but presently when I run the code (as is) it appears to do nothing - ie doesn't leave the sheet I run it from (and that's not where the range name data appears). I was originally running the code in Excel 2007 in a sheet with other macros but to try and get different results have moved them to a stand alone sheet with no other macro files open. Have also tried running them from a file saved as '97-'03 format. Neither yielded different results. Others with more experience than I (see the errors I made evidenced in comments discussion with Reafidy & bear in mind that my original posted code was result of material found through google and modified by me for specific task & application and implication that I am not savvy enough to have come up with it on my own) may find other solutions better for them but for now:

I am more than happy as Reafidy's code works for me.

As I am not registered (I did try but it didn't work) and don't have enough reputation points I can not vote but I have put a check mark next to Reafidy's solution.

FURTHER UPDATE:
I have now discovered that PaulStock & Jean-François Corbett's code wasn't working for me due to a very minor discrepancy on my part - the code contained "Data" whilst my named range was "data". Making this change (to allow for case sensitivity) in their code means that both of their solutions now work for me and hence I have attempted to add a tick to their solutions! Unfortunately I have found that only one solution can have a tick.

I have also learnt that I took Chris' code too literally. In an effort to test each code 'as is' that is what I did. A simple additon of 'wb.activate' in the section where he has 'do stuff' makes the code do what I want.

THANKS again for all four contributions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're doing a few convoluted things in your code, and I think that's what's confusing the issue.

Having you error handler (`abcd:`) start in the middle of a `For...Next` loop is incredibly bad practice and can only lead to confusion. I can't think of a reason why this should ever be done.

Anyhow, there's no need to use error handling for this task. I understand that there are exceptional cases where bad VBA design forces us to use error handling instead of what should be built-in VBA functionality (e.g. testing whether a non-Variant [array has been allocated](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbaarrays.htm)), but this is not one of those cases. There's a standard way to do it (`.Names` collection of workbook object), and using error handling instead of this is messy and convoluted and asking for trouble.

Also, why say

```
x = wb.Name
Workbooks(x).Activate
```

when you can just say `wb.Activate`? You're not using `x` for anything. Or `y`, for that matter.

The following works and is both simplified and optimised, relative to your original code as well as to the other answers that have been given up to now:

```
Sub zaa2()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim nm As Name

    For Each wb In Workbooks
        For Each nm In wb.Names
           If nm.Name = "Data" Then
                wb.Activate
                Exit Sub
           End If
        Next
    Next wb
End Sub
' A workbook containing a range named "Data" is now activated 
' (if one is found amongst the open workbooks). 
' Note that there may be more than one, but only the first found is activated...
```

**EDIT:** In your comment, you mention you had trouble due to confusion between uppercase `"Data"` and lowercase `"data"`. To guard against this in the future, one possibility is to ignore case. This could be done as follows:

```
If StrComp(nm.Name, "data", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
```

or

```
If LCase(nm.Name) = "data" Then
```

Both will return `True` if `nm.Name` is `"Data"`, `"data"`, `"dATa"`, etc.

Comment: your logic about wb.activate sounds good and I would thus agree with not needing x. Y however is used elsewhere (in the code that does other stuff not relevant to the basic problem). Bottom line though is above didn't work for me. Maybe something I'm doing?

Comment: Define "didn't work". I tested it and it works fine at this end.

Comment: @Jean-François Corbett - when I run the code it does not move from the sheet I started in (which doesn't contain the named range). It literally appears as if nothing happens. Please see my comments under UPDATE under original post - I am happy as I have a working solution, but can only assume that your code doesn't work in my environment or due to something else I am doing wrong. I have no idea what that might be.

Comment: @Jean-François Corbett - code now working when I change from "Data" to "data" - have elaborated under FURTHER UPDATE in original post.

Comment: @Jean-François Corbett, please see my edit for why I don't use the names collection.

Comment: @Jean-François Corbett, Care to explain why you have not removed your downvote as stated?  Perhaps they read my explanation of why this code fails.

Comment: I absolutely did not "revenge" down vote your answer.  That is very unfair and a completely false statement.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use error handling like that.  Either move the error handling out of the loop or reset the error handler each time it occurs, so use error handling like this:

**A much preferred alternative would be:**

```
Sub Test()

    For Each wb In Workbooks
        x = wb.Name
        Workbooks(x).Activate            

        If RangeExists("Data") Then
            y = wb.Name
            Exit Sub
        End If

    Next wb

End Sub
Function RangeExists(s As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    RangeExists = Range(s).Count > 0
End Function
```

**EDIT:**

@Jean-François Corbett,  I have to say you a very quick to jump on the down vote button.  The first solution I posted was because I made the assumption that the OP was not posting his entire code hence why I did not attempt to simplify it or "clean it up" like I usually do. I agree I did not word my answer well, but with regard to the first solution I was trying to demonstrate that he needed to reset the error handler.  Unfortunately I should have said a "prefered alternative would be".

@Derek,  Sorry I was unable to answer your further questions in time.  Obviously you are free to choose whatever method you like.  In my opinion the multiple loop solution provided by others which digs into the workbook name collection is unnecessary and long winded.  Now more importantly the name collection can contain names which refer to a constant, formula, or a range.  I presume you want to only check if the defined name is specifically a named range which means the looping method provided by others would need to be adjusted to be reliable.

I agree with comments made by others that error handling should be avoided BUT unnecessary looping in excel can be as much of an evil as using error handling and personally I avoid it like the plague.

The function above can be placed in its own module and be reused as much as you like.  It is quick, reliable, avoids unnecessary looping, checks SPECIFICALLY for a named range in a workbook and is the most widely accepted/used method for checking if a named range exists within the excel vba community (by this I mean using a function and error handling over looping through the name collection).  Do a google search for "Check If Named Range Exists" if you don't believe me.  Or ask at www.ozgrid.com/forum if you want other excel vba experts opinion's.

Now that I know you have posted your entire code and that you did not intend to activate every workbook, you could use this code which will activate the first workbook found with the named range "data":

```
Sub Test3()
    Dim wbLoop As Workbook

    For Each wbLoop In Workbooks
        If RangeExists("data", wbLoop) Then
            wbLoop.Activate
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next wbLoop

End Sub
Function RangeExists(s As String, wb As Workbook) As Boolean
   On Error Resume Next
   RangeExists = wb.Names(s).RefersToRange.Count > 0
End Function
```

I completely understand the need for positive Criticism and I believe in the down vote system if it is used correctly.  However, with two down votes for what I believe was a reasonable solution and along with my help with the ops formatting issues - unfortunately I cant help but feel like I want to distance myself from this forum.

Comment: Appreciate the responses as I'm the first to admit much of my code lacks polish. Tried both of above and got Compile error
End if without block if
on both. If I removed the end if line of code and ran it again it got essentially same result as my original code - only found the right sheet if it was 2nd in line of open sheets. Only difference when it didn't find the right sheet was didn't tell me there was an error, just left me on first sheet

Comment: Hi Derek, the code above will not throw a compile error.  You have either copied the code incorrectly or you have modified it in someway.

Comment: You should probably post your entire code for this procedure, then we may be able to help further improve our solutions.

Comment: Only modification I do is as described in comments on Chris Neilsen's solution. Code as I used it was: For Each wb In Workbooks x = wb.Name Workbooks(x).Activate If RangeExists("Data") Then y = wb.Name Exit Sub End If Next wb End Sub Function RangeExists(s As String) As Boolean On Error Resume Next RangeExists = Range(s).Count > 0 End Function and it returned the compile error. I note that posting on here is not showing the new lines so my code is not showing as I used it. I suspect that was what Mitch Wheat fixed in my original post.

Comment: Whilst my original post was not the entire code I have only omited that which is not relevant. When I test the solutions I test them 'as is', not with the addition of the stuff I intend to do once having found the file. Hope that helps!

Comment: Can you confirm that you have a new Line IMMEDIATELY after "If RangeExists("Data") Then" - exactly like I have.  If you tried to put more code on the same line after the word "Then" then I would expect to see the error end if without blocking if.

Comment: I did not have a new line at that point and with that correction am pleased to say it now works! Any idea how I can copy code directly rather than via word?

Comment: @Reafidy - thanks, please see my comments under UPDATE under original post.

Comment: @Reafidy - further testing on my part shows that test2 is not as good as test. I've also made other comments (more on other's solutions) in FURTHER UPDATE

Comment: I was suggesting you are quick to down vote in general, perhaps everyone else has followed your misleading comments?  You say its terrible practise but you have only stated "is incredibly bad practice & can only lead to confusion".  That's your opinion only. If you wish to down vote in future, be prepared to back it up with facts! I will remove the code as I don't like down votes. At the end of the day the code 100% worked.  Your's on the other hand doesn't specifically check for a named range. Perhaps it should not be advertised/replicated when there is a faster & more reliable solution?

Comment: How did I know you were going to say that?? I removed the answer because I don't like down votes and because it has drawn attention away from the other code I provided which was my intended solution.  I explained why I gave that answer & I still don't see cause for the big issue you have made about it.  You have failed to explain why you down voted, and failed to acknowledge the flaw in your code. I don't like the way you constantly post "-1 for ..." on so many peoples answers, you are quick to down vote and I don't believe its justified so much, hence my strong view above on your actions.

Comment: Don't flatter yourself, I simply made an observation.  From the FAQ:  "Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect."  I don't believe it states anything about opinion. Are you going to explain your issue with my code or not?

Comment: @Jean-François Corbett, I was asking you what your issue is with the code that you asked me to remove. You have still not justified why you down voted the code other than to say "is incredibly bad practice & can only lead to confusion".  That is opinion only.  Just like my statement you don't like is my opinion only.

Answer (score 1):

Heres an alternative method without getting fancy with the error handler

```
Sub zaa()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim CheckForNamedRange As Boolean
    Dim nm As Name

    On Error GoTo EH

    For Each wb In Workbooks
        CheckForNamedRange = True
        Set nm = wb.Names("data")
        If CheckForNamedRange Then
            ' Name found
            ' do stuff

            Exit For
        End If
    Next
Exit Sub
EH:
    If CheckForNamedRange Then
        ' Name not found
        Err.Clear
        CheckForNamedRange = False
        Resume Next
    Else
        ' Some other error occured, so handle it
        '...
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: not sure if I'm doing something wrong but when I tested this it seemed to do nothing. Note that when I try copying the code from here it doesn't stay in the same format so I paste it to word, get things on the right lines and then copy to vba & run. I haven't worried about the layout as I believe that is only about better readability rather than code function.

Comment: "without getting fancy with the error handler" -- are you kidding me? Certainly looks fancy than all the other methods to me. :)

Comment: @Derek if this and other suggested solutions arnt working for you I suggest you tell us all of what you are trying to do and post your whole routine.  I suspect your will have other contributing problems

Comment: @chris neilsen - thanks for your help, please also see my comments under UPDATE, appearing under my original post. I am happy as at least one of the proposed solutions works for me. I am testing the code 'as is' so I can only assume there is something about my environment or who knows what that is a contributing factor.

Comment: @chris neilsen - code works when I add 'wb.activate' under your 'do stuff'. Please see comments in FURTHER UPDATE in original post. THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. Shouldn't have to worry about getting errors.

```
Sub zaa()
    For Each wb In Workbooks
        x = wb.Name
        Workbooks(x).Activate
        For Each n In Workbooks(x).Names
           If n.Name = "Data" Then
                y = wb.Name
                Exit Sub
           End If
        Next

    Next wb
End Sub
```

Comment: Still got the Compile error
End if without block if
but when I removed the "end if" line from the code it works perfectly (as long as 'data' is a valid range in an open file)

Comment: You should not get that error, Paul's code is correct as is. I have a feeling you are placing "y= wb.name" on the same line as "If n.Name = "Data"" which is incorrect.  It must be on its own line.

Comment: Should be `Exit Sub`, not `Exit For`. Otherwise it just loops through all workbooks regardless of whether "Data" has been found. +1 when this is corrected!

Comment: @Jean-François Corbett, thanks for pointing that out.  I have corrected the code to be `Exit Sub` instead of `Exit For`

Comment: @Derek, I tested the code and did not get any compile errors as you did. Are you sure the compile error is coming from this subroutine, or could you be missing an `IF` statement somewhere else in your code?

Comment: @PaulStock - thanks Paul - compile error was my fault, I had left the y = wb.Name on the same line as the code above it due to problems I had been experiencing copying the code sample direct to vba. Whilst your code worked for me originally it has stopped doing so and I don't understand why. Currently it just cycles through the sheets to my last open excel file. It does not store anything as the variable 'y'. As with other solutions that don't work I can only assume it is something about my environment or something else I am doing wrong. My updates under original post may give u further info?

Comment: @PaulStock  - code now working when I change from "Data" to "data" - have elaborated under FURTHER UPDATE in original post.